# Colorbox with Dynamic Content not re-sizing correctly for Group

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have a group ColorBox that I want to display information from a dynamic source and also iterate over the group using the pervious and next buttons.

so:

```
$(".colorbox").colorbox({rel:'group', transition:"fade"});


<a class="colorbox" id="l_152957" rel="group" title="" href="object_snippet.php?id=152957" ><img src="images/46636_140.jpg" alt=""></a> 

<a class="colorbox" id="l_74911" rel="group" title="" href="object_snippet.php?id=74911" ><img src="images/46536_140.jpg" alt=""></a> 

<a class="colorbox" id="l_202703" rel="group" title="" href="object_snippet.php?id=202703" ><img src="images/46336_140.jpg" alt=""></a>
```

The html data in object_snippet.php is dynamically generated via the id=XXX url variable

I get this to work fine but after i click through the next and previous buttons colorbox does not resize to fit the content. The content is there but just in a very small window.

Any idea how one would make that happen and have the colorbox re size to fit the dynamically generated content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When colorbox loads ajax content, it adds the markup to the document then uses jQuery to measure the width and height.  Why wouldn't your markup report the dimensions you want it to be?  Is there a CSS problem?  Does the markup contain img elements that you didn't specify the dimensions for?

Comment: I have images of varying sizes and shapes (portrait/landscape) and I'm trying to display data along-side the image. I just put a width and height on the main div and it works better. Looks like I can also do this on colorbox as well. I'll just have to come up with a best fit for my data in terms of handling portrait/landscape.